# How can i set fucntions for each of these buttons using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

```
localStorage['serviceURL'] = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://goodsbuy.000webhostapp.com/";
var serviceURL = localStorage['serviceURL'];

var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { vScrollbar: false, hScrollbar:false, hScroll: false });

var employees;

$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(getEmployeeList, 100);
});

$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {

});

function getEmployeeList() {
    $('#busy').show();
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php', function(data) {
        $('#busy').hide();
         $('#employeeList li').remove();
        employees = data.items;
        $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
            var valuestop = employee.title;

            var now  = "30/11/2019 " + valuestop;
            var then = new moment();
            var difference = moment.utc(moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss");

            $('#employeeList').append('<li>'+
                    '<img src="js/citybus.png" class="list-icon"/>' +
                    '<p class="line1">' + employee.firstName + '</p>' +
                    '<p class="line2">' + difference +'</p>' +
                    '<button class="bubble" onclick="setReminder();">' + '<center><img src="js/bell.png" style="height:15px;width:15px;"/></center>' + '</button></li>');

        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            scroll.refresh();
        });
    });
}
```

I'm trying to create local notification when `<button class="bubble" onclick="setReminder();">' + '<center><img src="js/bell.png" style="height:15px;width:15px;"/></center>' + '</button>` buttons are clicked. The number of buttons depend on the items in the database. and these items have different values (different employee.firstName), I want each button to post its own employee.firstName in this function :

```
function setReminder() {
            cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
            id: 1,
            title: employee.firstName,
            text: "Your Bus Will Soon Be Here",
            sound: "js/when.mp3",
            icon: "js/citybus.png"
            });
            }
```

Comment: Don't use inline code. Having said that, you can add the employee name as `data-name="..."` to the button and use `onclick="setReminder(this);"`. Now use `function setReminder(btn)` instead and inside, use `btn.dataset.name` to grab the employee name from the button.

Comment: @Chris G what do you mean by adding data-name=".." to the button?

Comment: It's not easy with composing HTML strings but something like `'<button data-name="' + employee.firstName + '" class="bubble" ...>'` should work

Comment: Thanks @Chris G it worked

Comment: @Chris G Thanks again, but how can I also get the 'difference' associated with that button. I hope you understand

Comment: The exact same way; add it as `data-diff` attribute to the button, then use `btn.dataset.diff` in the function.